# Oracle trigger to disable direct update and delete from toad

Tags: oracle, security, plsql

I have an Oracle database with stored procedures. Now I have to insert, update and delete only through stored procedure and prevent direct insert, update and delete from toad

Comment: What should happen if somebody runs your stored procedure from TOAD?

Comment: More generally, please explain what business problem you are trying to solve. There are various to implement this, some are outright preventions, others are merely hurdles. So you need to give us more details. Also: which version and which Edition (Enterprise/Standard/Express) of Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you wan to restrict DML on a table to a defined set of sored procedures. Lets take the simplifying assumptions that you allow the DML operation regardless of how the procedure was called but only if the procedure was called. The following presents a skeleton for doing so.

```
Create a package that: 
  1. Define in the SPEC the DML routines. 
  2. Define in the SPEC a function that returns a value indicating whether the DML in allowed or not.
  3. Create in the BODY the DML procedures and the DML Validation function.
  4. Define in the BODY a package level control variable indicating DML Allowed or not.
  5. In the DML routines set he DML Allowed variable to allow the operation.
  7. In the DML routines always set the DML control variable to disallow the operation completes AND when any exception occurs.
  8. (optional) Define in the SPEC a user defined error number and message. 

Create a trigger which validates the control variable and throws exception if it's not allowed.
```

Skeleton For above: Assume table name=> 'My_Special_Table'

```
Create or Replace package My_Special_Table_DML as 
  Invalid_DML_Requested_num constant number := -20199; --Used define Error
  Invalid_DML_Requested_msg constant varchar2(80) :=
          'DML on My_Special_Table only allowed through DML routines in Package';

  Function  Is_DML_Allowed return boolean ;
  Procedure Delete_My_Special_Table (*parameter list as needed*);
  Procedure Update_My_Special_Table (*parameter list as needed)*;
  Procedure Insert_My_Special_Table (*parameter list as needed*);
end My_Special_Table_DML; 

Create or Replace package My_Special_Table_DML BODY as 
  DML_OK    boolean := false;      -- do not allow DML opperation 

  Function Is_DML_allowed return boolean is
  begin 
     return DML_OK; 
  end Is_DML_Valid ; 

  Procedure Delete_My_Special_Table (*parameter list as needed*) is
  -- declare local variables
  Begin 
      DML_OK := true ;
      ... other code as needed 

      Delete from My_Special_Table .... 

      DML_OK := false ; 
  exception 
     when <expected errors> 
          then
              DML_OK := false; 
              <code to handle expected errors>
     when others 
          then 
              DML_OK := false. 
              raise ;
  end Delete_My_Special_Table;

  -- *Code for Update and Insert similar to above Delete.*

end My_Special_Table;

Create or Replace Trigger My_Special_Table_DML_BIUD
    before insert or update or delete on My_Special_Table
is
begin 
    if not(My_Special_Table_DML.Is_DML_Alloewd)
    then 
        raise_application_error(Invalid_DML_Requested_num,
                               ,Invalid_DML_Requested_msg
                               ); 
    end if; 
end My_Special_Table_DML_BIUD;
```

I'll leave to you to figure out the logic of this and why it work. 
But note back APC's questions: "what happens if somebody runs the procedure from TOAD". In this case the DML would be allowed from any DB connection where user has execute authority on the package. Including but not limited to TOAD.